# A matrix with some cases for its entries

Tags: matrix

I'm beginner in Mathematica.

I have a $3 \times 3$ matrix, say $A$, in which some of its entries are nonzero (I know which entries are nonzero); for example the entries $a_{12}$, $a_{13}$, $a_{21}$, $a_{23}$ and $a_{31}$. But the nonzero entries can have 3 different values, say $x,y$ and $z$. I want to see determinant of $A$ in all these different cases. How can I do that?

Few months age I asked this question but in an ambiguous way, so I couldn't get the answer.

Bests,

Comment: It's remarkable that you asked the same question five months ago...

Comment: yeah, but that time my question was ambiguous and I couldn't get the answer.

Comment: But that time, you accepted an answer.

Comment: Maybe. but it doesn't work now

Comment: If instead of this discussions you answered me, everything was finished Henrik

Comment: What in `pat = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}};
vals = a @@@ pat;
A = SparseArray[pat -> vals, {3, 3}];
Det[A]` does not work?

Comment: @A.Mpi  wait.... *"If instead of this discussions you answered me, everything was finished Henrik – A. Mpi"* With such rude comments you expect to inspire anybody to **volunteer their time to look at your problem**?  Your question will be put [on-hold](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because it may be considered a [duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates).  You can [edit] your question if you consider this is a mistake and give great emphasis in what was NOT answered in the other question.

Comment: The OP has acknowledged to being a beginner.  Some of the comments are apparently at odd with what is written [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2340/2018-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire), including the view that the role of moderators is to welcome new users.

Comment: @tomd (1) OP is _not_ new to this site. (2) OP asked almost literally the same question five months ago _and accepted it_. (3) OP hasn't explained yet, why the answer to the old post is not satisfactory. So, what's wrong with marking this post as duplicate and telling the OP why it was done so?

Comment: @A.Mpi You appear to already have an answer to your question as quoted by Henrik above.  (The code with `SparseArray`.)  If this does not work for you, or you do not understand it, you should edit this question to clarify this specifically, not simply restate the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you simply  require something like the following?

```
myarr = (Array[a, {3, 3}] /. Thread[{a[1, 1], a[2, 3], a[3, 2]} ->  0]);
Det[myarr]
```

> a[1, 3] a[2, 2] a[3, 1] - a[1, 2] a[2, 1] a[3, 3]

```
nonzero1 = Thread[{a[1, 2], a[1, 3], a[2, 1], a[2, 2], a[3, 1], a[3, 3]} ->
{1, 4, 6, 8, 100, 3}];
nonzero2 = Thread[{a[1, 2], a[1, 3], a[2, 1], a[2, 2], a[3, 1], a[3, 3]} -> Range[6]];
nonzero3 = Thread[{a[1, 2], a[1, 3], a[2, 1], a[2, 2], a[3, 1], a[3, 3]} -> RandomReal[1, 6]];
```

```
Det[myarr] /. nonzero1
Det[myarr] /. nonzero2
Det[myarr] /. nonzero3
```

> -3218
>
> -58
>
> -0.168692